# I am looking for app to remove exif tags

Tags: software-recommendation, photo, tag

I am looking for application not to viewing, but to removing exif tags from photos. I know, that I can do it by opening file in text editor, but I hope that there is nice app for this. Can somebody give me a name (I spend some time on searching).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install jhead`

To use:

`jhead -purejpg /path/to/image.jpg`

For more information:

`man jhead`

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/):

```bash
exiftool -overwrite_original -all:all="" image.jpg
```

`exiftool` is a *very* powerful tool. Make sure to consult the manual (`man exiftool`) for more information.